# Replacing all characters in text file with specific character

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a file which looks like:

file.txt

```
NNNP
PPZL
ZZNN
```

I would like to replace all the letters to "N"  nd  have an output like this with the same number of lines as the input: 
(my file here has 3 line but in reality, my file has thousands of lines)

```
NNNN
NNNN
NNNN
```

Indeed, I can just create a new file with this command:

```
printf %4s | tr " " "N" > file2.txt
yes "$(<file2.txt)" | head -n3
```

However, does anybody know if there is a more straightforward way to replace all the letters at once and maintain the same matrix of columns and rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve it is `sed`:

```
sed 's/[A-Z]/N/g' file.txt
```

(add `-i` if you want in-place file changes).

PS. Note, that the expression above is case sensitive. If you want case-insensitive replacement use something like this:

```
sed 's/[A-Z]/N/Ig' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

To replace each alphabetic character by the letter `N`:

```
tr '[:alpha:]' N < file.txt > file2.txt
```